# How to improve query performance from sql execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express, sql-execution-plan

I have a table named `Product_Category_Mapping` with 16806030 rows. I have added a non-clustered index on `ProductId` and `CategoryId` columns of this table.

1. Number of records in `Product` table: 16899429
2. Number of records in `Category` table: 413

When I look at the execution plan of database, it uses an Index Seek with a cost of 83%.

Here is the query :

```
(SELECT 
     pcm.Id, pcm.CategoryId, c.Name AS 'CategoryName', 
     pcm.DisplayOrder AS 'CategoryDisplayOrder' 
 FROM 
     Product_Category_Mapping AS pcm 
 JOIN 
     Category AS c ON pcm.CategoryId = c.Id 
 WHERE 
     pcm.ProductId = @ProductId 
 FOR XML RAW, ROOT('Category')) AS 'Category'
```

For execution plan I have execute query from this: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-inefficient-query-88f4611f

Can anyone please suggest how to improve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question with your query.

Comment: Databases don't have execution plans, queries do.  If you want help with the query here, you should edit your question and put the query into the question.

Comment: I have edited my question with query

Comment: Most of the cost is in index seek,very good.So how long does it take?

Comment: @Mihai: Thank you for your quick response. I execute one SP. And in execution plan other tables have 0% cost, only this table have 83% cost. Moreover, when I execute this stored procedure with 645 ProductIds, it took 1:04 seconds to return result in SSMS.

Comment: Try adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of your query inside the proc.Also update you statistics `EXEC sp_updatestats`

Comment: Can you clarify if you have 2 indexes (one on each of the columns mentioned above) or one composite index which uses both columns?

Comment: @Mihai: Why this : OPTION(RECOMPILE)

Comment: When you run that proc the first time sql server creates an execution plan for the value in  @ProductId and sticks with that plan no matter if that value changes,or the tables data changes.So you recompile it each time it is run to create an appropriate execution plan,it adds a bit of overhead for the CPU but this is nothing compared with an inefficient execution plan.